# boost::phoenix::static_cast_ compile errors

Tags: c++, boost, casting, compiler-errors, boost-phoenix

I'm encountering a compile error when trying to static cast an argument inside of a boost phoenix lambda. The errors themselves are way too long, so I've posted them to pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2DDdZH7v).

I've created a minimal example showing what I am trying to do. If I make the variable b into an A pointer and thusly don't cast, then everything compiles and runs correctly. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Minimal example (compile with "clang++ -lboost_thread phoenix_test.cpp"):

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;
using namespace phoenix;
using namespace arg_names;
using namespace local_names;

class A
{
public:
    A(int a)
        : mA(a)
    {};
    int GetX() const {return mA;};
protected:
    int mA;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(int a)
        : A(a)
    {};
    int GetX() const { return mA + 1; }
};

int main (void)
{
    const A* a = new A(3);
    const A* b = new B(2);
    BOOST_AUTO(test, (_1->*&A::GetX)() + (static_cast_<const B*>(_2)->*&B::GetX)());

    std::cout << test(a, b) << std::endl;
    delete a;
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler used was clang 3.4, and gcc 4.6.3 was also tried.

Comment: ooops. Did you compile the right sample? [Your code compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8429237e1ff4840f) and the error references `dynamic_cast` only

Comment: You're right - I compiled the wrong sample. Nonetheless, I still get compile errors when compiling with static_cast_. [Here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bjLaSrHe) is the compiler message for static cast.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages seem to imply that you were using `dynamic_cast_` there.

Dynamic casts require virtual classes. Add a virtual member to the base class (e.g. the destructor)

Sample:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e3ae985f75664eb)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace px = boost::phoenix;
using namespace px::arg_names;
using namespace px::local_names;

class A {
    public:
        virtual ~A() {}
        A(int a) : mA(a){};
        int GetX() const { return mA; };

    protected:
        int mA;
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        B(int a) : A(a){};
        int GetX() const { return mA + 1; }
};

int main()
{
    const A* a = new A(3);
    const A* b = new B(2);
    BOOST_AUTO(test, (_1->*&A::GetX)() + (px::dynamic_cast_<const B*>(_2)->*&B::GetX)());

    std::cout << test(a, b) << std::endl;
    delete a;
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
6
```

Comment: I'm still getting errors with clang++ 3.4. Which compiler / version are you using?

Comment: The compiler errors I got when compiling your example are [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=P01Xjgey)

Comment: @Lejar mmm. that's very strange. Did you notice I added the destructor (IOW: did you actually copy the code?)

Comment: I've used clang-3.5, g++ 4.8.2 and 4.9 and 5.x. I just intalled clang-3.4 so I could test with that. Also, no problem.

Comment: Yes I copied the code directly from your sample. I think something's fishy with my compiler... I'll see if I can't find another machine to test this on..

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that I have boost 1.48 on the machine I'm developing on. On my server I tried everything with 1.54 and it worked. I assume I'm running into a problem like [this one](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6040).

Comment: When were you planning on telling us you use a 5 y/o version of the library :) Yes. That seems ... related. I hope you don't mind me wasting my time here then